# Perl Regex Find and Return Every Possible Match

Tags: regex, perl

Im trying to create a while loop that will find every possible sub-string within a string. But so far all I can match is the largest instance or the shortest. So for example I have the string

*EDIT CHANGE STRING FOR DEMO PURPOSES*

```
"A.....B.....B......B......B......B"
```

And I want to find every possible sequence of "A.......B"

This code will give me the shortest possible return and exit the while loop

```
while($string =~ m/(A(.*?)B)/gi) {
    print "found\n";
    my $substr = $1;
    print $substr."\n";
}
```

And this will give me the longest and exit the while loop.

```
$string =~ m/(A(.*)B)/gi
```

But I want it to loop through the string returning every possible match. Does anyone know if Perl allows for this?

*EDIT ADDED DESIRED OUTPUT BELOW*

```
found
A.....B
found
A.....B.....B
found
A.....B.....B......B
found
A.....B.....B......B......B
found
A.....B.....B......B......B......B
```

Comment: Could you show what you mean by "every possible match"?

Comment: e.g 

1st match  = start F F Q Q E R Q Q stop

Comment: 2nd = start F F Q Q E R Q Q stop R Q R R H A G C R H W Y G C E R R Q R Q H V F R R A G S S A N A T A A A E Q H R L L R S G Q V R Y P F stop

etc.. 

(sorry hit return by accident thats why 2 coments)

Comment: It's best if you edit your full expected output into the answer. Perhaps using a shorter string.

Comment: Im just thinking now I need to replace the first shortest substring and omit the stop don't I before looping again?

Comment: okay I will do that. 1 moment please

Comment: I get what you want from your sample, with your code. Perhaps something is different in your real program?

Comment: No I need to create an array of every possible match to perform some processing on each match later in the program. Its a bioinformatics project, I am searching for open reading frames in a translated dna strand

Comment: @PhilipButler Have you looked for an existing bioinformatics library that might do this?

Comment: Schwern, they do exist however I havn't been able to find one in Perl that allows me to look at the code. I was hoping to use regex to solve this but I may need to resort to searching the string manually char by char

Comment: (1) Is it always the same between A's (all B's in this case), or can there be different things in between? (2) There is no closing A in your example -- does there have to be one, or not?

Comment: @zdim, there will be one or many As and one or many Bs with a range of non A,B chars of any length in between a given A and B

Comment: the periods are just used for demonstrative purposes above

Comment: i.e A is the beginning marker for a sub-string and B is the end marker

Comment: Ah, now the  problem makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to parse the string so to scoop up what you want.

For example, use regex to step through all `A...A` substrings and process each capture

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $s = "A.....B.....B......B......B......B";

while ($s =~ m/(A.*)(?=A|$)/gi) {
    my @seqs = split /(B)/, $1; 
    for my $i (0..$#seqs) {
        say @seqs[0..$i] if $i % 2 != 0;
    }   
}
```

The `(?=A|$)` is a lookahead, so `.*` matches everything up to an `A` (or the end of string) but that `A` is not consumed and so is there for the next match. The `split` uses `()` in the separator pattern so that the separator, too, is returned (so we have all those B's).  It only prints for an even number of elements, so only substrings ending with the separator (`B` here).

The above prints

```
A.....B
A.....B.....B
A.....B.....B......B
A.....B.....B......B......B
A.....B.....B......B......B......B
```

There may be bioinformatics modules that do this but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Super answer. very concise, exactly what I need

Comment: @PhilipButler Great :)  Let me know if testing with real data shows problems, or if other questions pop up

Comment: I learned something new with `my @seqs = split /(B)/, $1; ` - didn't know about capturing the delimiter before.

Comment: To skip the redundant non-B-ending lines you can do `say @seqs[0..$i] if ($seqs[$i] eq 'B');`

Comment: @Automaton  Thank you, fixed. I didn't pay close enough attention to what should be extracted.  I use the (even) number of elements rather than testing against `B` so that it doesn't involve the actual separator.

Comment: @PhilipButler  Fixed the printing statement to drop the redundant elements, what I missed. Now it extracts (and prints) what is shown in the question.